# How can Nodejs apps always run as a Windows service?

Tags: node.js, windows-services, pm2

I have windows Server 2016 cloud hosting. I broadcast my sites on IIS.

I have 2 apps running on Nodejs. I log out of windows after configuring my applications.

My IIS sites continue to run, but my nodejs applications quit when I log out or restart windows.

I have followed the steps below to fix this issue.

1. I installed the **pm2** library. Globally.

```
npm install --global pm2@latest
```

2. I installed the **pm2-windows-service** library. Globally.

```
npm i pm2-windows-service -g
```

3. I installed the **pm2-windows-startup** library. Globally.

```
npm install pm2-windows-startup -g
```

4. I uninstall running services to avoid running apps repeatedly.

```
pm2 kill
```

5. If there are any running services, I first uninstall it.

```
pm2-service-uninstall
```

6. I installed the **pm2-service-install** library. I named it "pm2Service1". I see it started when I enter services.msc.

```
pm2-service-install -n pm2Service1
```

7. I start the startup service for applications to start when Windows opens.

```
pm2-startup install
```

8. I go to the directory where the application is installed and run the application with pm2. (If I don't enter the directory and run it, it gives an error. Can't read the sql / file.sql file.)

```
c:
cd C:\webSites\myService1
pm2 start app.js
```

9. I check the application with list and show, and see if it works.

```
pm2 list
pm2 show 0
```

After making sure it works.

10. I'm recording running applications.

```
pm2 save --force
```

When I do these procedures and log off windows, I can access the application from outside.

But when I restart windows the application does not work. I have to repeat the same steps every time it starts up.

When Windows restarts, "pm2Service1" seems to be working. But pm2 list the lists as empty.

Comment: alternative solution

I deleted the libraries pm2, pm2-windows-service, pm2-windows-startup. I copied nssm.exe to the directory. (https://nssm.cc/)  I ran the codes below.

`nssm install myService "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
nssm set myService AppDirectory "C:\\WebSites\\demoWebSite\webService\\"
nssm set myService AppParameters app.js
nssm set myService AppStdout "%~dp0myServiceIn.log"
nssm set myService AppStdout "%~dp0myServiceOut.log"
nssm set myService AppStderr "%~dp0myServiceError.log"
nssm start myService`

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this on my servers by using NSSM Service. Once you install it, go to NSSM folder and type

```
nssm install PM2
```

You can find the entire tutorial here:

https://lakin-mohapatra.medium.com/register-pm2-as-a-service-in-the-windows-server-747f19e2ff2a

Answer (score 1):

`pm2-windows-service` is DEPRECATED.
I have no experience with `pm2-windows-startup` but I think it adds an entry to the registry to start pm2 after user login, which is too late.

Here is my working [example](https://github.com/hagaigold/WinPM2).

Answer (score 0):

Best practice AFAIK is using nssm + "windows batch file" to start your app.js, for more details you can check [this](https://blog.cloudboost.io/nodejs-pm2-startup-on-windows-db0906328d75) link.